# Solve $(x^2+2x)^{x^2-3x}=12$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, quadratics, index-notation

Found this problem in a mathematics group site. I suspect it cannot be solved with pen and paper. Graphically $x=-2.438$ and $x=3.267$ but can it be solved algebraically? The answer was not posted on the site.

Comment: Use MathJax to make your question clear. Add your efforts to get answer(s).

Comment: I sincerely doubt you can non-numerically find roots of $(x^2-3x)\ln(x^2+2x)-\ln12$, even with [the Lambert $W$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Answer (score 1):

One can approximate the solution if required, rather say a pen and paper solution.
Given that $(x^2+2x)^{x^2-3x}=12$

take log with base 10 on both sides, $(x^2-3x)\log(x^2+2x)=\log12$

LHS has domain $x\in(-\infty,-2)\cup(0,\infty)$, and LHS<0 for $x$ in interval $(0,3)$ . When $x>3$, the function has $f'(x)>0$, i.e. increases. Therefore, one solution is greater than 3. Testing $x=4$ in the original equation gives the result $331776$ which is extremely high, hence we can predict the solution lies is in interval $(3,3.5)$.

The second solution is smaller than zero. Note than LHS is not for $(-2,0)$ and shows similar behaviour as with x>3 in mirrored sense [image]
Testing for limit of 2 and 3 does the trick again.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was probably not possible.

Comment: Is there something else you're looking for in the answer which i should have included?

Comment: No, I had worked on it for quite a while before I went to graph it in Desmos since I could not figure it out algebraically. I was just seeing if anyone could see a way to answer it algebraically that I had not thought of. Thanks

Comment: then update your question body and clarify pen and paper and include what you have worked upon.